# Highcharts | Heatmap | Legend filters not working when updating data

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

I have an issue with how the *setData* function works with a series of kind '**HEATMAP**', when **updating** the data, and when one or more **legend filters** have been disabled.

I use 3 colors to fill the Heatmap chart according to the value represented by the data (which works fine) , each color is shown as an item in the legend :

```
options.colorAxis = {
      dataClasses: [
{
      color: GREEN,
      from: 0,
      to: 50,  
    },
    {
      color: ORANGE,
      from: 50,
      to: 100, 
    },
    {
      color: RED,
      from: 100,  
      to: 1e6,
    }]

    };
```

When I want to update the chart with new data coming from a server, I use :

```
this.chart.series[0].setData(newData, true, false, false);
```

This works fine as well, **except** when colors have been disabled by clicking on the legend items.

The problem is that all the colors that were filtered out by the filter reappear  on the chart when data is updated ( image below , part 3 )

However, the legend is ok (what was disabled remains disabled).

Can you please help me find a solution ?
Thank you.

Please find below the visual description of what I explained :

[image]

Comment: Please add a [MCVE]

Comment: please find visual description of what I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, this is how I solved my problem.

Right after updating with

```
this.chart.series[0].setData(newData, true, false, false);
```

I just added the lines below ( toggle programmatically twice the visibility of the data groups ) :

```
const allItems = (<any>this.chart.legend).allItems as Array<any> ;

allItems.forEach( item => {
  item.setVisible();
  item.setVisible();
});
```